# Debian 9 WIFI driver problems (fresh install)

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers

On a fresh install of debian 9 I'm having problems with installing the proprietary broadcom drivers.

I followed [this guide](https://wiki.debian.org/wl) exactly.

but on the final step I get the error `modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.0-1-amd64`

I've seen a lot of "fixes" for this, but nothing seems to work. The output for `sudo find / -name "modprobe*"` is:

```
/sbin/modprobe
/lib/modprobe.d
/proc/sys/kernel/modprobe
/etc/modprobe.d
/usr/share/man/man5/modprobe.d.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/modprobe.8.gz
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/modprobe
```

The command `lspci` :

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac  Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03) 

Subsystem: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:0619] 

Kernel modules: bcma 04:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge [1b21:1080] (rev 03
```

and `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux testing _Stretch_ - Official Snapshot amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20170306-05:25]/ stretch main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux testing _Stretch_ - Official Snapshot amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20170306-05:25]/ stretch main

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ stretch main


deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main


deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free


deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main contrib non-free


deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free


deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Comment: What is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` ?

Comment: `03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43a0] (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Broadcom Limited BCM4360 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:0619]
        Kernel modules: bcma
04:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge [1b21:1080] (rev 03)`

Comment: Please [edit-here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/350691/edit) by adding the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Answer (score 2):

The [`broadcom-sta-dkms`](https://packages.debian.org/fr/stretch/broadcom-sta-dkms) is available on debian stretch , you don't need to add jessie repos ( it is not recommended ).

Because  `broadcom-sta-dkms` is a `non-free` software you should add the `non-free` component to your `sources.list`.

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follows:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main contrib non-free
```

Update your system

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Remove the `broadcom-sta-dkms`

```
apt-get remove broadcom-sta-dkms
```

Follow [the official guide](https://wiki.debian.org/wl) to install the wifi driver (posted on your question)

```
apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') broadcom-sta-dkms
modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma
modprobe wl
```

Comment: By removing all of the jessie sources, I now have the erorr: `E: Package 'broadcom-sta-dkms' has no installation candidate` when I try to follow the instructions again. My sources file is a mess, could you please edit your comment to show *exactly* what it is I need in there?

Also updating throws the error :`'http://ftp.us.debian.org stretch Release' does not have a Release file`

Comment: Wiping my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and adding in the free + non-free repos from the bottom link solved my problem (switching out "jessie" for "stretch"). Then followed the steps from the original link: https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList

Answer (score -2):

Try from synaptic to install broadcom-sta-sources instead of the dkms.